# Convert file directly to XLSX format using Spire.XLS

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, spire.xls

I have **XLS** file with **macro**, to convert it to OpenXML format, I am using **Spire.XLS** and able to convert file to **XLSM** format. Then using **OpenXML SDK** to convert **XLSM** file to **XLSX** format like below:

```
string lstrOpenXMLXLSMIPDTemplatePath = pstrIPDTemplatePath.Replace(".xls", ".xlsm");

Spire.Xls.Workbook lobjDSTemplateWorkbook = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
lobjDSTemplateWorkbook.DisableMacrosStart = false;
lobjDSTemplateWorkbook.LoadFromFile(pstrIPDTemplatePath);
lobjDSTemplateWorkbook.SaveToFile(lstrOpenXMLXLSMIPDTemplatePath, Spire.Xls.ExcelVersion.Version2013);

pstrOpenXMLIPDTemplatePath = lstrOpenXMLXLSMIPDTemplatePath.Replace(".xlsm", ".xlsx");

using (var XLSMStream = File.OpenRead(lstrOpenXMLXLSMIPDTemplatePath))
using (var XLSXStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    XLSMStream.CopyTo(XLSXStream);
    using (var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(XLSXStream, true))
    {
        doc.DeletePartsRecursivelyOfType<VbaDataPart>();
        doc.DeletePartsRecursivelyOfType<VbaProjectPart>();
        doc.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(pstrOpenXMLIPDTemplatePath, XLSXStream.ToArray());
}
```

Is there any to convert file directly to **XLSX** format with **Spire.XLS Dll** or **some other way**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Spire.XLS dll to convert XLS to XLSX format directly using the below code:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

workbook.LoadFromFile("input.xls");

//Set the version to Excel 2007 or above
workbook.SaveToFile("output.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
```

Comment: if .xls macro contains macro, it is not allowing to convert .xlsx directly. It will be corupted. You need to convert to .xlsm first.

Comment: Which version did you use? I can convert xls file with macro to xlsx successfully using Spire.XLS -Version 8.9.8. I suppose it might be a bug in your current version.